# React native - Keeps adding android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

My app doesn't need to read phone state so I'd like to remove the permission from my react native app.

Every time i delete it from everywhere in the project, it is re-added again when I run `./gradlew assembleRelease`

How do I get it to stop adding it in?

Comment: projectFolder/android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml from this file, add or remove all permission.

Comment: thanks @IrfanAli I was also editing the wrong menifest file i.e. `projectFolder/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use android manifest merging

Add new file `android/app/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml`

with contents

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
</manifest>
```

Done! More about manifest merging: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_priorities , section **Merge priorities**

Comment: It's adding again and again even after adding your solution

Comment: @MohammadKashifSulaiman add it to `android/app/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml`. It's android menifests merging mechanism: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html - see _Merge priorities_ section on provided docs page

Comment: Works like a charm!  Wanted to confirm it works since the only comments (so far) are that it doesn't.

Comment: After creating new folder and manifest file i am not able to get screen where imei required .